# Giving apache process kill permission under linux

Tags: php, linux, apache, process, permissions

I am running a web server serving a php page that uses `exec("kill -9 PID")` to kill certain processes on the host machine. My problem is that it's not working and I figured out it's because apache doesn't have permission to use the kill command on any processes. What I need exactly is how to give my php script the permission to kill any process given its pid which I assumed comes back to giving the user apache that permission, please correct me if I am wrong.

> N.B: I tried using posix (with SIGKILL) which is properly installed on the server to no avail

Comment: Run the process you want to kill under the same user as apache is running under. Its not a good idea to let apache kill whatever it wants as it is a security issue.

Comment: I agree with @John's comment.  Or use sudo.